# How grant Cypress test application some permissions

Tags: json, config, settings, manifest, cypress

I'm working on Copy-Paste test so i'm looking for a way to grant Cypress the Clipboard permissions. Where these browser setting are?

Because as i've read [googleDevPage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) i need to add the permission manually to the **manifest.json** in test app to allow Cypress get done these tests automaticaly without manual access grant.

[image]

Seems to be i'm looking for Cypress app configurations.

Comment: Please answer your own question if you found a solution to this. I'm struggling with the same thing.

Comment: @heap1 unfortunately no, I havent found a way

Answer (score 6):

We have a similar issue with one of our tests. We were using the clipboard in our app, so when cypress was trying to run the code, didn't have the permissions.

So executing this code before the action of using the clipboard, worked for us:

```
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
      command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
      params: {
        permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
        // make the permission tighter by allowing the current origin only
        // like "http://localhost:56978"
        origin: window.location.origin,
      },
    }))
```